# Show unselectable value in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, default-value

I have many drop down lists in many files. I'm trying to write a function to just display "---Please select--" as the default item each time the page loads - which upon post back cannot be selected and hence added to the  database nor added to the list as a new item,. i dont know how to achieve this. instead I'm using insert (which I know is wrong) but i dont know which is the right way to achieve this. please advise

ASPX

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListVType" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceVesselType"
 DataTextField="Vessel_Type" DataValueField="VType_ID" Width="160px" AutoPostBack="False"
  CausesValidation="True" OnDataBound="ddl_DataBound">
```

CS
....

```
PublicFunctions pubvar = new PublicFunctions();

protected void ddl_DataBound(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
           pubvar.ddl_DB(DropDownListVType);


    }
```

PUBLIC FUNCTIONS CS

```
 public void ddl_DB(DropDownList d)
{
    try
    {
        d.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Please Select ---", String.Empty));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
    }

}
```

UPDATE:
PUBLIC FUNCTIONS CS

```
    public object checkNull (Control c)
    { 
    try{

       if (c.GetType()==typeof(TextBox))
       {
           TextBox tb = c as TextBox;

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
            {
                return tb.Text;
            }

        }

        if(c.GetType()==typeof(DropDownList))
        {
            DropDownList dl = c as DropDownList;

             if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.??
            {
                return c.???
            }

        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
    }
    return (DBNull.Value);
```

CALL in PAGE CS

```
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VType_ID", DropDownListVType.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: why would the insert approach be incorrect? Where exactly do you have trouble?

Comment: each time the page posts back, the ---Please Select--- is added as a new Item in the drop down list

Comment: check if it exists beforehand then...

Comment: please advise how to do that?

Comment: Then add it only if !Page.IsPostBack

Comment: @Plue im entering it just like u wrote it but its not coming up with the option to select .IsPostBack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright... As you insert your default option to the index 0 you can just do the following:

```
if(!d.Items[0].Text.equals("--- Please Select ---"))
    d.Items.Insert("--- Please Select ---");
```

and else do nothing. or as @Plue mentioned:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    d.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Please Select ---", String.Empty));
```

Additionaly you should probably move `"--- Please Select ---"` to a constant.

```
private const string DEFAULTOPTION = "--- Please Select ---";
```

Comment: The OP main issue is making the first element not selectable

Comment: @plue you sure about that??

Comment: Title : Show unselectable value in dropdownlist

Comment: @voguel if nothing is selected for that field (which is not mandatory) the form doesnt go through... i have a checkNull function which determines if anything in any form is not entered (for fields that accept nulls), then null will be inserted into the database. how to i use that with this to make it work? see the updated code for the checkNull function as well as as how i'm currently calling it in the CS page

Comment: your checknull only works with controls of type TextBox. you could just use: `c.Value` instead of `tb.Text`. this then checks every Control's value if it's null or empty. The value property returns the ListItem.Value of the currently selected Item (if c is a DropDownList), if you use Text, you probably get ListItem.Text (which is not helpful)

Comment: i just included it as a separate if statement. See the UPDATE above its not allowing me to write c.value.

Comment: try dl.SelectedValue then

Comment: the dropdownlist ended up being mandatory, so this works like a charm. if i come across another that isnt mandatory i'll see what happens then. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your aspx :

```
<asp:DropDownList ...  AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="-Choose car-" disabled="true"/>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This will display **-Choose car-** by default. Then, when the user click on the ddl, this option won't be selectable.

And do not insert anything in code behind.

**Edit**

If you bind with each postback, try adding this to your ddl_DB code :

```
d.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Please Select ---", String.Empty));
d.Items[0].Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: i have validation on other fields. if i simply click save before even entering anything the fields that are validated comes up with its respective errors, but the value in the drop downs i have on the page automatically defaults to the first item from the respective lists instead of showing --please select-- again

Comment: Do you bind your data with each postback?

Comment: Yes. Data is bound with each postback

Comment: I'm not sure of what your issue is. Are you saying that my method works on page load, but when postback occurs, the first item of the bound list is shown instead of --please select-- ?

Comment: With your code, is --please select-- inserted multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

If you always have a "---Please Select---" option or something similar as the default value. You could always just ignore the first ListItem in each dropdown.

```
myDropDown_OnSelectedIndexChanged(...){

    if(myDropDown.SelectedIndex != 0){

    //Do stuff, make database changes, etc

    }
```

}

If the goal is to never allow this control to be selected, put something like this:

```
try
{
    if(!IsPostBack){
        ListItem defaultOption = new ListItem("---Please Select---", String.Empty);
        d.Items.Insert(0, defaultOption);
        defaultOption.Attributes.Add( "disabled", "disabled" );
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
}
```

Comment: the --Please Select-- cannot be stored in the database at any index. this assumes that?